# Why is my FirebaseAuth instance still have the user in FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I go through this [Build an Android App Using Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible#creating-project) tutorial and I'm confused about why the `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` keeps returning the user even if I run this code:

```
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    Toast.makeText(Application.getInstance(), status.getStatus().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mainAdapterOnChange();
                }
            });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    Toast.makeText(Application.getInstance(), "revokeAccess: status = " + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

I think pressing the **Google sign-in button to authenticate the user** is working, because after I `GoogleSignInApi.signOut` and press the button again, I can select the Gmail account to log in with.

But why is my `FirebaseAuth` instance still have the user in `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to signout of the firebase instance also then only current user will be removed. Try this code

```
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

U can try out this latest [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

Comment: Yes that worked, i think, but what is the the more detail  workflow differences between GoogleSignInApi.signOut vs FirebaseAuth.signOut() and GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess. Yes i will post a new question because what is "really" happening with this calls